# How to run multiple .net services on same machine

Tags: c#, service, installutil

We have a .Net service that we need to run more than once on the same machine. I have my exe and support files residing in 2 different folders: c:\folder1\ and c:\folder2\

But when I issue either of the following, the ServiceName does not change to what I want it to be:

```
"c:\folder1 - someId\install\InstallUtil.exe" /servicename="My Service Name 1" "C:\folder1 - someId\MyNameSpace.MyAppName.Service.exe"

sc create "My Service Name 1" binpath="C:\folder1 - someId\MyNameSpace.MyAppName.Service.exe" DisplayName= "My Service Name 1"
```

If no service has been created, the InstallUtil will register my service but not with the serviceName that I specify.

If a service is registered (for example folder1 service), then the InstallUtil will error on the folder2 registering with a "specified service already exists".

The sc command only shows the help info for the sc command as if I have the wrong syntax.

What is the proper way to register the same service multiple times on the same machine?

Comment: Are you giving it a different name for folder2?

Comment: Do you have the service name embedded programmatically anywhere?

Comment: InstallUtil.exe itself has no use for an /servicename option.  Your own [Installer] is supposed to use any additional options, available through the Installer.Context property.  We can't see what your Installer class looks like but it is kinda guessable.

Comment: My exe has same name in each folder. I'll look at the Installer.Context property.